# How to record and save video using HTML5 WebRTC

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular6, webrtc

> First run code snippet then read the description ...
> It will give you the structure

I want to record, play and save video in the 2nd `video element`. The problem I am facing is: stream is running in the 1st `video-element` but unable to record and save video

```css
.video {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Welcome to WebRTC</h1>
    <video class="video" #video autoplay controls></video>
    <video class="video" style="width:360;" autoplay controls #recordedVideo></video>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="startRecording()">Start</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="stopRecording()">Stop</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="playRecording()">Play</button>
</div>
```

#### ------------------------ Modified and Resolved the issue

What I did here, in [Luis Estevez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6716036/luis-estevez) code, I declared the event there in `startRecording` method because when I tried to push stream-chunk in blob-array, it responded an error: push method does not exist, even I created an object-array after I declared an array.

```
startRecording(stream) {
    let options = { mimeType: 'video/webm' }
    this.recordedBlobs = []
    console.log(this.recordedBlobs)
    try {
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options)
    } catch (e0) {
      console.log('Try different mimeType')
    }

    console.log('Created MediaRecorder', this.mediaRecorder, 'with options', options)
    // this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.handleStop
    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
      console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event)
      const videoBuffer = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, { type: 'video/webm' })
      this.downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBuffer) // you can download with <a> tag

      this.recordVideoElement = this.recordVideoElementRef.nativeElement
      this.recordVideoElement.src = this.downloadUrl
    }
    // this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.handleDataAvailable
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data)
      }
    }
    this.mediaRecorder.start(100) // collect 100ms of data
    console.log('MediaRecorder started', this.mediaRecorder)
  }
```

Thanks [Luis Estevez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6716036/luis-estevez) :)

Comment: this is not working in the mobile browser any suggestion?

Comment: @ChhaiyaHarshad Sorry, I haven't gone through such experience. Can anyone help him? Post your question with the code snippet, may be someone can respond you with the working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have the same code snipped at per your example. But it didn't work on a mobile browser.

@Luis Estevez Let me know if you have any idea or suggestion for the same.

Comment: Done. It's working. @WasiF I have another issue with a voice in the recording. There is too much voice disturbance. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ChhaiyaHarshad I don't have exact solution but I think you need to use some sort of voice fixing libraries because as far as I know WebRTC does not provide such feature. You may confirm their docs if they have such option to improve voice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't 'really' record the stream, you just copied the stream object, not the event data coming from the stream.

Use [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and pass the stream as constructor argument. Grab the video *blob* from the event handler ondataavailable. Join the recorded array of blobs to a new Blob. From there you can get url using `createObbjectURL(blob);`

The follow snippet is pseudo code:

** typescript doesn't recognize 'MediaRecorder' so you'll have to find a way to add type any to MediaRecorder

---

```
mediaRecorder: any;
recordedBlobs: Blob[];
downloadUrl: string;

handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
      this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}

handleStop(event) {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
    const videoBuffer = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
    this.downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBuffer); // you can download with <a> tag
    this.recordVideoElement.src = this.downloadUrl;
}

startRecording(stream) {
    let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
    this.recordedBlobs = [];
    try {
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    } catch (e0) {
        console.log('Try different mimeType');
    }
    console.log('Created MediaRecorder', this.mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.handleStop;
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.handleDataAvailable;
    this.mediaRecorder.start(100); // collect 100ms of data
    console.log('MediaRecorder started', this.mediaRecorder);
}

stopRecording() {
  this.mediaRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', this.recordedBlobs);
  this.recordVideoElement.controls = true;
}

playRecording() {
  if (!this.recordedBlobs.length) {
      console.log('cannot play.');
      return;
  }
  this.recordVideoElement.play();
}

async ngOnInit() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 360 } }).then(stream => {
    this.videoElement.srcObject = stream
    this.startRecording(stream);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying to implement your provided solution but facing issues i.e. every event call of MediaStream, `null` the already created objects like in `handleDataAvailable` event, I declared in class constructor as `this.recordedBlobs = new Array<Blob>()` but this event make `this.recordedBlobs` undefined.

Comment: handleDataAvailable pushes the blob coming from mediaRecorder.ondataavaiable to `recordedBlobs`. recordedBlobs should never be undefined. We only assigned value once to it using `this.recordedBlobs = new Array<Blob>();` and it  *shouldn't* be in event `handleDataAvailable`. Can you add the new code you tried to the bottom of your question?

Comment: @WasiF add the console.log(s) I wrote and then show the logs.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried pushing data to an array that does exist yet. did you assign `his.recordedBlobs = new Array<Blob>()` before handling data event?

Comment: Can you tell how to record screen? I have tried with `facingMode: 'screen'`, `mediaSource: "screen"` but in vain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular pls help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

### Complete working code to record Video in Angular 6

#### RecordComponent.ts

```
  @ViewChild('recordedVideo') recordVideoElementRef: ElementRef
  @ViewChild('video') videoElementRef: ElementRef

  videoElement: HTMLVideoElement
  recordVideoElement: HTMLVideoElement
  mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
  recordedBlobs: Blob[]
  isRecording: boolean = false
  downloadUrl: string
  stream: MediaStream

  constructor() {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.videoElement = this.videoElementRef.nativeElement
    this.recordVideoElement = this.recordVideoElementRef.nativeElement

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: {
        width: 360
      }
    }).then(stream => {
      this.stream = stream
      this.videoElement.srcObject = this.stream
    })
  }

  startRecording() {
    this.recordedBlobs = []
    let options: MediaRecorderOptions = { mimeType: 'video/webm' }

    try {
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, options)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

    this.mediaRecorder.start() // collect 100ms of data
    this.isRecording = !this.isRecording
    this.onDataAvailableEvent()
    this.onStopRecordingEvent()
  }

  stopRecording() {
    this.mediaRecorder.stop()
    this.isRecording = !this.isRecording
    console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', this.recordedBlobs)
  }

  playRecording() {
    if (!this.recordedBlobs || !this.recordedBlobs.length) {
      console.log('cannot play.')
      return
    }
    this.recordVideoElement.play()
  }

  onDataAvailableEvent() {
    try {
      this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event: BlobEvent) => {
        if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
          this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data)
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  onStopRecordingEvent() {
    try {
      this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (event: Event) => {
        const videoBuffer = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, { type: 'video/webm' })
        this.downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBuffer) // you can download with <a> tag
        this.recordVideoElement.src = this.downloadUrl
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

}
```

#### RecordComponent.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Welcome to WebRTC</h1>
    <video class="video" #video autoplay controls></video>
    <span class="m-1"></span>
    <video class="video" style="width:360 !important;" controls #recordedVideo></video>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" *ngIf="!isRecording" (click)="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" *ngIf="isRecording" (click)="stopRecording()">Stop Recording</button>
  </div>
```

Note: if you get an error that [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) is not found etc then do

`npm i @types/dom-mediacapture-record`

Be sure to update your `Chrome` browser too.

Have a Good day

Comment: I tried your code. but it is not working. Getting error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @ManeeshRao put that code in `ngAfterViewInit` method, it's looking like it is being read before its html rendering.

Comment: I have added the code.  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true,
    }) But getting lot of echo noise? any suggestion?

Comment: I am not able to record the audio. It is recording video only.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that. I could no longer continue this project.